# Show how a parquet file is replicated and stored on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

Data stored in parquet format results in a folder with many small files on HDFS.

Is there a way to view how those files are replicated in HDFS (on which nodes)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you actually want to track which data blocks is on which data node and that's not apache-spark specific.

You can use **hadoop [fsck](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck)** command as followed :

```
hadoop fsck <path> -files -blocks -locations
```

This will print out locations for every block in the specified path.